# Linking rows in a data frame

Tags: r

I have a data frame with 4 columns.

```
m <-c(1,2,3,4)
e <-c('01/01/1970', '02/01/1981','03/05/1986','01/01/1970') 
z <-c(111,123, 151, 111)
l <-c('XAR', 'XAR', 'XUI','XUI' )
q <-c(673, 673, 304, 455)
df <- data.frame(m,e,z,l,q)
```

I need to create a new df that describes the relationships between rows.
There is a relationship if rows match other rows in any 2 out of the 4 fields

For instance :

[image: data frame view]

The resulting df in this case would be :

[image]

In my production data there are 700,000 rows.  I've tried to solve this using SQL but the recursive nature of the function makes it too slow for production purposes

I wondered if R/R packages had any graphing capability to make this practical.

Comment: What is your expected output?  Perhaps check `igraph`

Comment: Some kind of object describing the links - this could be a simple dataframe  with 2 columns containing the m and m's that are linked.

Answer (score 1):

It's not entirely clear what output you expect.

In any case, `data.table` makes it easy and fast to identify rows with common values:

```
library(data.table)

# convert your data frame into data table
  setDT(df)

# create common id for rows with same values in 'e' AND 'z'
  df[, id_ez :=.GRP, by=.(e,z)]

# create common id for rows with same values in 'l' AND 'q'
  df[, id_lq :=.GRP, by=.(l,q)]


> head(df)
>    m          e   z   l   q id_ez id_lq
> 1: 1 01/01/1970 111 XAR 673     1     1
> 2: 2 02/01/1981 123 XAR 673     2     1
> 3: 3 03/05/1986 151 XUI 304     3     2
> 4: 4 01/01/1970 111 XUI 455     1     3
```

Now you can get a two-column output that tells you which 'm' is liked to each id

```
df[, .(m_linked=paste(m)), by=id_ez]

>    id_ez m_linked
> 1:     1        1
> 2:     1        4
> 3:     2        2
> 4:     3        3
```

If you want to turn this table into a list of vectors:

```
mysplit = split(a$V1, a$id_ez)
myresult = lapply(mysplit, as.character)

> myresult
$`1`
[1] "1" "4"

$`2`
[1] "2"

$`3`
[1] "3"
```

Comment: The match occurs when any 2 of the fields match i.e. Could be E-Z, E-L, E-Q, Z-E, Z-L, Z-Q etc..

Comment: hummm it's a bit trickier then, since you want identify rows with the same values in at least two of by all possible pairs of 4 columns .... I'll leave my answer as a partial response, but I guess you need make this point more clear in the question and let's hope someone comes up with the solution

Comment: Thanks for your feedback.  I've edited the question.